# Get list of cms pages in magento2.1

Tags: php, magento2

I need to get list of cms pages in phtml template file.

Below code will used in magento 1.9x version

```
$results = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('field'=> 'title','like' => "%{$search}%"),
        array('field'=> 'content','like' => "%{$search}%"),
     ))
     ->addFieldToFilter('is_searchable', 1);
```

1. How to get cms pages in magento2.1
2. Need to add custom field in cms page

Answer (score 0):

i Hope This will be helpful for you,

```
namespace Creare\DynamicSitemap\Block;  
class Dynamicsitemap extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;        
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getCreareCMSPages(){
    $this->getStoreId(); // current store id

    $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
    foreach($page->getCollection() as $item)
    {
        echo "page id : ".$item->getId() . ':: page name title : ' . $item->getTitle().'<br/>';
    }
    die();   
    $page = $this->pageFactory->create()->load(1);
    var_dump($page->getData());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your class constructor

```
protected $pageCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory $pageCollectionFactory,
    ...
) {
    ....
    $this->pageCollectionFactory = $pageCollectionFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use this in one of your class methods.

```
$collection = $this->pageCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter([
        ['field'=> 'title','like' => "%{$search}%"],
        ['field'=> 'content','like' => "%{$search}%",
     ])
     ->addFieldToFilter('is_searchable', 1);
```